# Selenium - Finding element that has title

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following element:

```
<button class="k-button k-button-icontext min-button-width" title="Add Matter (Access key + A)" onclick="addMatterToBill();return false;" accesskey="a">
<u>A</u>
dd Matter
```

How can I locate that element using c#? I have tried the following:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@title= 'Add Matter (Access key + A)']")
```

and that did not work. I am not an expert at Xpath, so I better read/learn about it.

The actual text on the button is: Add Matter which is found in the above html between the `<u>`.

Any help will be more welcome.

Answer (score 6):

*The target element is a `button`, not an `input`*:

```
//button[@title = 'Add Matter (Access key + A)']
```

You may also check the `title` attribute with `starts-with()`:

```
//button[starts-with(@title, 'Add Matter')]
```

Comment: Thanks Abel - Not sure how why I used 'Input' as a target instead of button. The solution worked perfectly fine. Just at the back of it, do you know a proper website where Xpath is well and fully explained along side examples?

Comment: Thanks Alecxe for these URLs

Comment: @Patrick sure, the last one is SO-specific - just for you to understand the basic concepts and how the QA system works here.